# PHP: Effective way to check if character belongs to a set of letters

Tags: php, string, conditional-statements

Using PHP 7.1.2-3+deb.sury.org~xenial+1.

I'm trying to write a conditional which checks the $lastCharacter variable to see if it is one of these: K, Q, N, B, R

I started with something like this:

```
$lastCharacter = 'K';

if ($lastCharacter = 'K' || $lastCharacter = 'Q' || $lastCharacter = 'N' || $lastCharacter = 'B' || $lastCharacter = 'R') {
    echo $lastCharacter . " is in series.";
    // result: K is in series.
}
```

Seems redundant to repeat ***$lastCharacter =*** so many times.

Then I attempted the following but it was somehow manipulating the $lastCharacter variable so that it equaled 1. Guessing the condition evaluated as true, resulting in the boolean 1 value. Still weird how it changes the variable.

```
$lastCharacter = 'K';

if ($lastCharacter = 'K' || 'Q' || 'N' || 'B' || 'R') {
    echo $lastCharacter . " is in series.";
    // result: 1 is in series.
}
```

So because ***$lastCharacter*** suddenly equals 1, I have to redefine to be able to use it again within that conditional. Sidebar: Why does it convert to 1?

I've seen alternatives to this approach where they check to see if a certain character is in a string but I'm trying to test if the last character of a string is one of these: K, Q, N, B, R.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try using an array:

```
$series = array('K', 'Q', 'N', 'B', 'R');

if(in_array($lastCharacter, $series)) {
    echo $lastCharacter . " is in series.";
}
```

If you ever have a contiguous range you can use:

```
$series = range('M', 'X');
//or
$series = range(1998, 2017);
```

Might be easier to use a string:

```
$series = 'KQNBR';

if(strpos($series, $lastCharacter) !== false) {
    echo $lastCharacter . " is in series.";
}
```

Answer (score 3):

`=` is assignment, `==` is comparison. So you (usually) don't want this:

```
if ($x = 1) ...
```

But (usually) this:

```
if ($x == 1) ...
```

That said, you might use `in_array()` to make your code a bit shorter:

```
if (in_array($lastCharacter, ['K','Q','N','B','R'])) ...
```

Edit: In order to prevent this issue, some programmers prefer to write comparisons this way:

```
if (1 == $x) ...
```

This way, if you typo and instead use the single `=`, you'll get an error instead of a silent assignment. This is called a [Yoda conditional](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yoda_conditions) because it's kinda backwards to the way you'd normally say it.

Answer (score 2):

Probably something like this?

```
// Array of symbols and two strings just for testing
$set = array( 'a', 'm', 'g' );
$string1 = 'something';
$string2 = 'other';

// if latest symbol of $string1 is in the $set
if ( in_array( substr( $string1, -1 ), $set ) ) { 
    // yes
}

// if latest symbol of $string2 is in the $set
if ( in_array( substr( $string2, -1 ), $set ) ) { 
    // yes
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To check for equality you must use the `==` operator.  You are reassigning the variable every time you write `$lastCharacter = 'SomeValue'`

The reason you are getting 1 in your result is because the expression `'K' || 'Q'`etc evaluates to true (1) and then you are setting $lastCharacter equal to the value of that expression.

Use the equality operator correctly like so...

```
$lastCharacter = 'K';

if ($lastCharacter == 'K' || $lastCharacter == 'Q' || $lastCharacter == 'N' || $lastCharacter == 'B' || $lastCharacter == 'R') {
    echo $lastCharacter . " is in series.";
}
```

Or try using an array of values like this

```
$lastCharacter = 'K';
if (in_array($lastCharacter, array('K', 'Q', 'N', 'B', 'R')) {
  // do stuff
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
  $lastCharacter = 'K';
  $arrayOfValues = array('K', 'Q', 'N', 'B', 'R');
  if(in_array($lastCharacter,$arrayOfValues))
  {
      // found
  }
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$lastCharacter = 'K';
$characterSet = ['K', 'Q', 'N', 'B', 'R'];

if (in_array($lastCharacter, $characterSet)) {
    echo $lastCharacter . " is in series.";
}
```